# Is `this` necessary to access member variables of typescript classes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, binding, this

In the class below, I use `this` 9 times to deal with member variables and functions. It's clogging up all my beautiful code! Is there anything that I can do to make it prettier? For example, is there anyway to access the `context` member variable without referring to `this`?

```
//controls timing and game phases.

import { Context } from "./helpers/Context"
import { Model } from "./Model"
import { View } from "./View"

export class Controller {

    context : Context;

    constructor(context : Context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    //make other objects in context, add them in.
    begin = () : void => {
        this.context.model = new Model(this.context);
        this.context.view = new View(this.context);
        this.init();
    } 

    init = () : void => {
        this.context.model.init();
        this.context.view.init();

        //causes an error! help.
        this.context.model.preloadModels([ 
            "/models/bleachers.obj"
        ], () => { this.buildWorld(); })
    }

    buildWorld = () : void => {
        this.context.view.makeGrass();
        this.context.view.makeSkybox();
        this.context.view.makeBleachersOnEdgeOfField();
    }

}
```

Comment: One way is to use factory functions instead of classes, but I don't know if that's a viable solution for you.

Comment: @ShamPooSham. Interesting! Tell me more?

Comment: It looks kinda wonky, but in essence you create a function instead of a class, and you use closure functions instead of instance methods inside of it. Have look at this medium post. https://medium.com/programming-essentials/class-vs-factory-function-exploring-the-way-forward-73258b6a8d15

Answer (score 2):

If you're used to languages like C or Java where you don't have to use `this` for class fields, it can look weird at first. I thought the same thing too. But for languages like Javascript and Python, it's normal to write `this` and `self` a lot of times. I think it's just a language-specific style thing that can look ugly to someone who is not used to seeing it, but this is the normal way and most JS programmers would not think it's ugly because they are used to it.

Comment: Ok! Understandable. It just seemed like half of the words I was writing was `this`, and it seemed "wrong".